# Top level declarator error but the program runs correctly

Tags: c++, oop, gcc, codelite

I have a project with multiple files including main.cpp and two headers. Both headers have an error at the line with class name declaration. Building any of the files or project as a whole gives no errors or warnings. The program itself runs correctly.

I'm using CodeLite IDE and GCC compiler.

What can be a reason for such behaviour and could it lead to any issues in the future?

```
#include <Creature.h>
#include <Party.h>

int main() { 
    // Does something with the stuff from header files.
    return 0;
}
```

Inside Creature.h:

```
#pragma once

class Creature { // Error: expected ';' after top level declarator
    // something
};
```

Inside Party.h:

```
#pragma once

class Party { // Error: expected identifier or '('
    // something
};
```

Comment: Is that actually the entirety of your code?  Based on the error, my guess is that a type somewhere isn't being terminated with a semi-colon.

Comment: @Stephen Newell Yes it is the entirety of program minus the content of the brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your IDE thinks that the header files are written in C (where `class` is not a keyword and so `Creature` is a declarator), because you gave them the conventional extension **`.h`** used to indicate that.  Don't do that: use `.hh`, `.hpp`, or `.hxx` for C++ header files so that tools (and humans) know what you're writing without having to understand the file.